# How to retrieve or print "Catch" info logging buffers?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, catch-unit-test

Using the [Catch single-include unit-tester](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/logging.md), I have (passing) tests like this

```
TEST_CASE ("sizes", "[metadata]" ) {
    INFO ( "The number is " << 42 );
    REQUIRE (sizeof(some_struct) == 16);
}
```

The documentation (linked above) states that the INFO is logged to a buffer, but I haven't figured out how to dump or otherwise retrieve the buffer. The message is not printed to my console, but other things I `printf` or shove into `cout` and `cerror` do print, so my i/o is set up correctly.  I tried reading the source to find out where messages are stowed, but it's big and involved.  I wonder if someone just happens to know how to retrieve the messages?

Comment: Did you look at the `INFO` macro to see what it's doing? Maybe trace into it in a debugger to see where it leads.

Comment: Yeah, the debugger `gdb` fails to load the executable (just says "File format not recognized.") The macro calls into the guts of the octopus, into a variable named "Info," for which there are almost 700 matches in the file. Reading the source bottom-up was going to be time-consuming, and that's why I posted the question: to see whether someone just happened to know.

Comment: The `gdb` problem was traced to mixed linking of C and C++ and eliminated. But it looks like the catch functions are aggressively inlined, so my attempt to step into `INFO` doesn't do anything. Still looking for advice.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is the intended behavior: INFO is reported only on failure. See
https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/issues/290

Comment: That is, indeed, the case. If you want it to print the message regardless of failure you can use WARN. I'm aware that that is not ideal and I have it on my soft list to look at adding an alternative.